# Phase Difference of A Mass-Spring System For Different Starting Points

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

[image] I’ve seen a very similar question (almost identical) in a test, but the answer key of the test said that it's quarter of a cycle (90 degrees). I'm a bit confused. Are they the same if you subtract 90 degrees from 360, you would get three quarter of a cycle? Or which one is perfectly true?

**The Answer Key of The Test Mentioned:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the different phase values in a table to make this easier to talk about. The position can $L,0,R$ meaning left, center and right and the velocity can be $L,0,R$ meaning moving to the left, standing still and moving to the right. I defined the zero phase as the start stretched and then release (the top configuration).
$$
\begin{array}{l|lllll}
\text{phase (degrees)} & 0 & 90 & 180 & 270 & 360 \\
\text{position}        & R & 0  & L   & \color{red}{0}   & R   \\
\text{velocity}        & 0 & L  & 0   & \color{red}{R}   & 0  
\end{array}
$$
We notice the bottom configuration is located in the red column at 270 degrees. So based on this table 270 would be the right answer. But you could also call 270 degrees -90 degrees and if you don't care about the sign then you could say the difference is 90 degrees.

If you started out with the bottom configuration at the zero phase then the top configuration would be at 90 degrees. So you have two options

1. If you define the top configuration as 0 degrees then the bottom configuration would be at 270 degrees from the first
2. If you are interested at the minimal phase difference then you would say the phase difference is 90 degrees.

Both answers could be correct and if the test wants you to pick one of those it should specify what is expected.

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes perfect sense.